# Status of Migration is Done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

When I was migrating something on rails I got a problem. And now after I migrated it, the status went down. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: can you be more clear on your question? what error are you getting?

Comment: My bad, I was writing this in a hurry. I am currently working on an application on rails, and I got to the point where I had to install ImageMagick and paperclip. I successfully installed imagemagick, but when I started migrating paperclip I keep on getting an error saying that I have "Multiple migrations have the name AddAttachmentImageToListings".

Answer (score 0):

Often when you write complex migrations, you run into situations where half of the migration succeeded but the other half failed, and now the migration is stuck in a weird half-done state where you can't run it again (because it's already partly run, so will throw an error about duplicate columns) and you can't undo it (because it's partly not run, so it will throw an error about missing columns or whatever). When *that* happens you pretty much need to go into the database and manually get things into the right state.

But if I understand you correctly, that isn't the problem you're facing. If you're getting an error with the migration *name*, then the *entire* migration will have failed to run (this is a good thing). The solution is to rename the migration (both the file and its class name on the first line) to be something unique, then try `rake db:migrate` again.

Hope that helps!